# Detect row selection change from inside a cell component

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) for some data needs in my application and have created a few custom cell.s

I currently have a custom cell with an "Edit" button that toggles the row selection and its editibility. There is also a button external from the grid to allow for selecting all rows (as shown in the screenshot)

[image]

What I would like to do is have the button change from "Edit" to "Cancel" when the row is highlighted (either by clicking the "Edit" button or when all rows are selected programmatically).

From with in the cell I can get the current row selection by doing `cell.getRow().isSelected()` but I don't see a way to detecting when a particular row selection has changed.

One solution I have in mind is to use CSS to hide/show the "Edit" or "Cancel" button since Tabulator will add the class `tabulator-selected` to anything that is highlighted. But this seems more like a hack.

Thanks in advance for the thoughts, opinions and comments!

---

In case it's relevant, I'm using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) wrapped in a [Vue](https://vuejs.org) component. The custom cell is just vanilla JS at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what appears to be a suitable way of detecting row-selection change from with in a cell. It uses the MutationObserver API and checks the row-element for the `tabulator-selected` CSS class.

(I also opened a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1821), so maybe in the future there will be a different way to handle this)

```
/**
 * A custom formatter/cell to enable the selection of an individual row
 *
 * @param {Object} cell Tabulator Cell object
 * @returns {HTMLElement}
 */
export default function(cell) {
  const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
  checkbox.onchange = function() {
    cell.getRow().toggleSelect()
  }

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  function mutationCallback(mutationsList) {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
      // if you are using something other than a checkbox, you would perform the element changes in there
      checkbox.checked = mutation.target.classList.contains('tabulator-selected')
    }
  }

  // Create an observer to only watch for attribute changes (like CSS classes) and activate it
  const rowEl = cell.getRow().getElement()
  // list of all available config options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit
  const config = { attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['class'] }
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback)
  observer.observe(rowEl, config)

  return checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach would be to use a formatter on the cell that sets the selected state of the toggle based on the selected state of the row, which can be retrieved using `cell.getRow().isSelected()`

you could then use the ***rowSelectionChanged*** callback and the ***reformat*** function on the row component to trigger a reformat of that row when its selection state is changed:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowSelectionChanged:function(data, rows){
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            row.reformat();
        });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

there are callbacks built into Tabulator that tell you when row selection has changed, ***rowSelected***, ***rowDeselected*** and ***rowSelectionChanged***. Full documentation of these can be found in the [Callbacks Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/callbacks#select)

It is only safe to change the formatting of cells in the formatter, so you want to watch for the change of selection on a row and then trigger a reformat of that row:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowSelectionChanged:function(data, rows){
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            row.reformat();
        });
    },
});
```